# Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in IndexController.php

Tags: magento-1.9, module, database, controllers

This Question is asked many times but still it's unresolved with definite solution. I am following this tutorial to implement the module http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-5.html.

I am getting this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\magentoapp\app\code\local\Mudit\Weblog\controllers\IndexController.php on line 9

while trying to fetch the data from the database table in the IndexController.php while others get this error in core files of magento abstract.php

Please, check the code for the config.xml, Blogpost.php and IndexController.php.

Please, help I am stuck with this from last 2 hours.

**etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<!--
    The module's node contains basic
    information about each Magento module
-->
<modules>

    <!--
        This must exactly match the namespace and module's folder
        names, with directory separators replaced by underscores
    -->
    <Mudit_Weblog>

        <!-- The version of our module, starting at 0.0.1 -->
        <version>0.0.1</version>

    </Mudit_Weblog>

</modules>

<frontend>
    <routers>
        <weblog>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Mudit_Weblog</module>
                <frontName>weblog</frontName>
            </args>
        </weblog>
    </routers>
</frontend>

<global>
    <models>

        <weblog>
            <class>Mudit_Weblog_Model</class>
            <!--
            need to create our own resource, can't just
            use core_resource
            -->
            <resourceModel>weblog_resource</resourceModel>
        </weblog>

        <weblog_resource>
            <class>Mudit_Weblog_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <blogpost>
                    <table>blog_posts</table>
                </blogpost>
            </entities>
        </weblog_resource>

    </models>
</global>
```

**Model/Blogpost.php**

```
class Mudit_Weblog_Model_Blogpost extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
protected function _construct()
{
$this->_init('weblog/blogpost');
}
}
```

**Model/Resource/Blogpost.php**

```
    <?php class Mudit_Weblog_Model_Resource_Blogpost extends   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
    $this->_init('weblog/blogpost', 'blogpost_id');
    }
    }
    ?>
```

**Controllers/IndexController.php**

```
<?php class Mudit_Weblog_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action 
{

public function testModelAction() 
{
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $blogpost = Mage::getModel('weblog/blogpost');
    echo("Loading the blogpost with an ID of ".$params['id']);
    $blogpost->load($params['id']);
    $data = $blogpost->getData();
    var_dump($data);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: did you create `Magentotutorial/Weblog/Model/Blogpost.php`?

Comment: My namespace is **Mudit** instead of **Magentotutorial**. You can see in code for the Blogspot.php I have created **class Mudit_Weblog_Model_Resource_Blogpost** and location of **Blogpost.php is app/code/local/Mudit/Web‌​log/Model/Blogpost.ph‌​p**

Comment: class name represent the file location too. add the code kindly add you are good to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**etc/modules/Mudit_Weblog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mudit_Weblog>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mudit_Weblog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Mudit/Weblog/controllers/IndexController.php**

```
<?php 
class Mudit_Weblog_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action 
{
public function indexAction()
{
    echo "sdfds";
}
public function testModelAction() 
{
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $blogpost = Mage::getModel('weblog/blogpost');
            echo get_class($blogpost);

    echo("Loading the blogpost with an ID of ".$params['id']);
    $blogpost->load($params['id']);
    $data = $blogpost->getData();
    var_dump($data);
}
}
?>
```

**Mudit/Web‌​log/Model/Blogpost.ph‌​p**

```
class Mudit_Weblog_Model_Blogpost extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('weblog/blogpost');
    }
 }
```

**Mudit/Web‌​log/Model/Resource/Blogpost.ph‌​p**

```
<?php class Mudit_Weblog_Model_Resource_Blogpost extends   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
    $this->_init('weblog/blogpost', 'blogpost_id');
    }
    }
    ?>
```

**Mudit/Weblog/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Mudit_Weblog>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mudit_Weblog>
    </modules>
    <global>

        <models>
            <weblog>
                <class>Mudit_Weblog_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>weblog_resource</resourceModel>
            </weblog>
            <weblog_resource>
            <class>Mudit_Weblog_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <blogpost>
                    <table>blog_posts</table>
                </blogpost>
            </entities>
        </weblog_resource>
        </models>
    </global>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <weblog>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mudit_Weblog</module>
                    <frontName>weblog</frontName>
                </args>
            </weblog>
        </routers>
    </frontend>

</config>
```

Comment: No it there in the code

Comment: @muditmehrotra are the classes are same too?

Comment: Blogpost.php is already in the Model folder. I have edited my question and made changes in the file paths

Comment: i know it is there but the you added the class `Mudit_Weblog_Model_Resource_Blogpost` that is looking for `Mudit/Weblog/Model/Resource/Blogpost.php` so follow this answer and add these file with this code then tell me output

Comment: Should I move the Blogpost.php file from **Model/** to **Model/Resource/** ?

Comment: yes you moved it and add new file  `Mudit/Web‌​log/Model/Blogpost.ph‌​p` that are mention in answer too

Comment: I have follow the same steps as you mentioned above create a separate file in **Mudit/Web‌​log/Mode‌​l/Blogpost.ph‌​p** and moved previous resource file to **Mudit/Web‌​log/Mode‌​l/Resource/Blogpost.ph‌​p** but still getting same error 
`Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\magentoapp\app\code\local\Mudit\Weblog\controllers\IndexController.php on line 10`

Comment: can you update your code with latest code?

Comment: I have updated please check

Comment: delete `cache` folder in `var/cache`

Comment: All cache deleted from the var/cache location but still same error.

I am calling this url `http://127.0.0.1/magentoapp/weblog/index/testModel/id/1`

There is a data field in the database from id 1

Comment: i added the `config.xml` replace with your's

Comment: replaced the config.xml with yours but still same error :( don't why. Its looks perfect now but same error `Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\magentoa‌​pp\app\code\local\Mud‌​it\Weblog\controllers‌​\IndexController.php on line 10`

Comment: did you add the table in database let me post my all code so can look at them.

Comment: updated the code that is working on my system

Comment: Updated my code exactly same like yours but still same error don't know the reason. Thanks a lot for your efforts same code working on your but not working on mine system. It's quit frustrating all looks good but still same error continue

Comment: @muditmehrotra did this code showing class `echo get_class($blogpost);`

Comment: no its not showing class name

Comment: last option delete var/cache and give 777 to file & folder.

Comment: It should show class name right?

Comment: remove the load code and then try... it is showing correct class (Mudit_Weblog_Model_Blogpost) ?

Comment: Cleared all cache, restart wamp server but it's not showing class it means there is issue with class instance. Instance not created

Comment: check you module is listed in admin or not? system > configuration > advanced

Comment: Yes Mudit_Weblog module is listed in admin and its enable

Comment: Thanks for the help now its working fine. I have removed all code and redo all things again after that it start working. Thanks.

Comment: @QuaisarSatti I have already marked it as accepted answer. I have some other query can you please help me in that also, please find my query here:

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132249/how-to-add-custom-entity-from-admin-in-magento

No one is there to suggest some solution please check.

Comment: @muditmehrotra kindly see this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for accepting the answer

Comment: @QuaisarSatti I have less then 6 reputation that is why stackexchage system not showing my accepted answer publicly but it accepted as internal. Can you please check my other question.

Comment: @muditmehrotra accepting answer is not related to your reputation you can accept answer just follow the link i provide. i have looked the question it already answered.

Comment: See response from stackexchange:
[![1.png](https://s14.postimg.org/w0fnc8zcx/image.png)](https://postimg.org/image/tj3w4zfgd/)

Comment: @muditmehrotra you are trying to upvote that need 15 reputation. kindly click ✔ to accept the answer

Comment: Ohh now it accepted

Comment: Do you have any comments for my another question:

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132249/how-to-add-custom-entity-from-admin-in-magento

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44337/discussion-between-qaisar-satti-and-mudit-mehrotra).