# How to enable login for custom cms page in magento-1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, login

I am working on https://www.depoto.com/bulkorders/
website, if any customer clicks on Bulk order page, need to ask for login for non-loggedin users. I created this Bulk order page in cms.

My customer.xml file is as below:

```
<default>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="cms"><label>Bulk orders</label><URL><![CDATA[https://www.depoto.com/bulkorders/]]></URL><title>Bulk orders</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
        </reference>
</default>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple add restriction on link

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
 ?>
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('bulkorders'); ?>">bulkorders</a>
<?php
} else {
?>
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'); ?>">bulkorders</a>
<?php 
} ?>
```

for login user

```
<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="cms"><label>Bulk orders</label><URL><![CDATA[https://www.depoto.com/bulkorders/]]></URL><title>Bulk orders</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>
```

not login user

```
<customer_logged_out>
 <reference name="top.links">
     <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Bulk orders</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Bulk orders</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
 </reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara updated the answer too..

Comment: where and how can i have to add this code at my customer.xml plz tell me

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara in the place of your existing code..

Comment: Means, i have to replace my customer.xml with above both?

Comment: nope replace with this code `<reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="cms"><label>Bulk orders</label><URL><![CDATA[https://www.depoto.com/bulkorders/]]></URL><title>Bulk orders</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
        </reference>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44341/discussion-between-teja-bhagavan-kollepara-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: I gave this page in form action. now i need to get the logged user details, how to do that?

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara see this answer for getting current user detail http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132249/how-to-add-custom-entity-from-admin-in-magento/132571#132571

Comment: @Qaiser Satti, Actually, i mean, if any customer place the bulk order, admin need to get the email with user details. i put the custom details before we enabled login option. now, after login, admin need to get email with customer details.

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara code i used is for current login user  feel free to use that. if you find this not helpful kindly  post question with ur requirement