# Magento Customer created from code not login to the website

Tags: magento-1.9, module, custom, customer-account

I am creating a customer from the code for a specific group code created a new record in the `customer_entity` table but when I try to login from the website its shows `invalid username or password` error while the customer created from the magento admin panel working fine and login to the website and redirect to the account page. check my code below:

```
public function editAction()
{

    $oenologist = Mage::getModel('tandem_oenologistuser/oenologist');

    if ($oenologistId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false)) 
    {
        $oenologist->load($oenologistId);

    }


    if ($postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost('oenologistData')) 
    {
        try {
            $oenologist->addData($postData);
            $oenologist->save();


            if(!$this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
            {
                $name = $postData['name'];
                $email = $postData['email'];
                $password = '1234567';
                $groupId = 4;
                $websiteIdVal = 1;

                $websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
                $store = Mage::app()->getStore();

                $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
                $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteIdVal)
                         ->setStore($store)
                         ->setFirstname($name)
                         ->setEmail($email)
                         ->setPassword($password)
                         ->setGroupId($groupId)
                         ->setIsActive(1);

                try{
                    $customer->save();
                }
                catch (Exception $e) {
                    Zend_Debug::dump($e->getMessage());
                }

            }

            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                    $this->__('The oenologist has been saved.')
                );


            return $this->_redirect(
                'tandem_oenologistuser_admin/oenologist/edit',
                array('id' => $oenologist->getId())
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        }


    }


    Mage::register('current_oenologist', $oenologist);


    $oenologistEditBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
        'tandem_oenologistuser_adminhtml/oenologist_edit'
    );


    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_addContent($oenologistEditBlock)
        ->renderLayout();
}
```

Also, its add the website id to 0. I need to check the user on login for this specific group and redirect user to a custom controller action which is the user's custom profile page or is there any way i can customize the account page.

I have used the [this](http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/programmaticaly-adding-new-customers-to-the-magento-store/) link to create the users programmaticaly.

Comment: are customers getting email after save?

Comment: right now its on my local machine

Comment: are you creating user in admin side?

Comment: @QaisarSatti : users created from the admin->customers->manage customers->add new customer can login the website but I am creating user from the custom module for a specific group those users are unable to login on the website.

Comment: i am asking it is frontend or backend?

Comment: creating in the backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this is happens when you are creating user from admin panel. i have faced the similar situation once time.after the save i have to update the wesite to make user working

```
 $customer->save();
 $custid=$customer->getId();
 $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($custid);
 $customer->setWebsiteId(1);
 $customer->save();
```

Comment: I have updated my code above please check this is the custom admin manageable module add/edit action i am creating the user when new record added.

Comment: you user problem will be solved after adding this code. because on creating  the user it get default website id 0 so you have to update after save.

Comment: Thanks again its working now. 

I need to check the user on login for this specific group and redirect user to a custom controller action which is the user's custom profile page or is there any way i can customize the account page.

Comment: yes there is alway a way post the question the community will provide the answer

Comment: Can you please check my [Question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133818/how-to-customize-the-customer-account-after-login-according-to-user-group)