# How to customize the customer account after login according to user group

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, customer-account, customer-group

I need to show the different options according to group of the customer in MY ACCOUNT section.

For example, I need to show only **My profile**, **Account Information**, **social media** accounts link in the **MY ACCOUNT** section of the customer dashboard. Some of links will be custom controller actions so how I can show these link and manage the session so that all this happened only when the customer is login.

Comment: you want to change navigation for the customer?

Comment: yes want to show different links according to the group of the user.  These links contains custom controller actions so I also need to manage the session on those pages.

Comment: @QaisarSatti Can you please have a look at my question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133806/magento-2-1-how-to-extend-product-listing-in-your-custom-product-list-and-appl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Go To ( YourTemplate/customer/account/navigation.phtml )

Step 2: Replace This Line: `<?php $_count = count($_links); ?>`

```
<?php $_count = count($_links); /* Add or Remove Account Left Navigation Links Here -*/
    unset($_links['account']); /* Account Info */     
    unset($_links['account_edit']); /* Account Info */            
    unset($_links['tags']); /* My Tags */
    unset($_links['invitations']); /* My Invitations */
    unset($_links['reviews']);  /* Reviews */
    unset($_links['wishlist']); /* Wishlist */
    unset($_links['newsletter']); /* Newsletter */
    unset($_links['orders']); /* My Orders */
    unset($_links['address_book']); /* Address */
    unset($_links['enterprise_customerbalance']); /* Store Credit */
    unset($_links['OAuth Customer Tokens']); /* My Applications */
    unset($_links['enterprise_reward']); /* Reward Points */
    unset($_links['giftregistry']); /* Gift Registry */
    unset($_links['downloadable_products']); /* My Downloadable Products */
    unset($_links['recurring_profiles']); /* Recurring Profiles */
    unset($_links['billing_agreements']); /* Billing Agreements */
    unset($_links['enterprise_giftcardaccount']); /* Gift Card Link */
?>
```

if you want to do this in **module** then override

```
<customer_account>
   <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>modulename/customer/account/navigation.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

for checking the session

checing the session of user

```
if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
             $this->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);

        $this->_redirect('customer/account');
        return ;
    }
```

getting the customer group

```
$customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$customerData->getGroupId()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me do this way. will get back to you. Thanks again.

Comment: for Step 1 you mean this path: app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/account/navigation.phtml

Comment: @muditmehrotra yes

Comment: Now I know how to show/hide the navigation  link according to the group but how to add a custom controller action as a link and open its content in the dashboard. For example, `Controller action->Profile
View->template/modulename/profile.phtml`
Now I need to add the **profile** as link in the navigation and show the **profile.phtml contents inside the dashboard**.

Comment: for that you have rewrite the customer controller.

Comment: Is there any example for that so i can also do that

Comment: here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92172/how-to-override-the-controller-accountcontroller

Comment: Please, check my question. Would be great help. [Question Link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134448/how-to-add-price-for-the-customer-group-and-add-it-to-the-customer-registration)

Comment: any suggestion on my question? 
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134448/how-to-add-price-for-the-customer-group-and-add-it-to-the-customer-registration

Comment: Can you please check my another question here :
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134782/magento-1-9-how-to-add-customer-group-on-registration-page

Comment: any suggestion on my question. why my registration page don't show group names