# How to add price for the customer group and add it to the customer registration page

Tags: magento-1.9, module, customer, customer-account, customer-group

I need to add price for the customer group from magento admin so each customer group have a different price. I also need to show these group with group price on the customer registration page on the frontend so when some customer create his/her account he/she need to select a customer group plan after filling the form user will be redirect to the payment gateway like paypal for the payment of the selected group price after successful payment customer will redirect back to our website and this way his/her registration is completed. How I can implement this logic as I am new to magento. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can set  discount on customer group...

Comment: @Qaisar Satti : client requirement is customer will register on some plan their will be free, premium plan if user register himself in free plan product price will be higher and if user select premium one products prices will be lower but how I can achieve this as there is no option to add customer group price. Cannot add discount to customer group he want customer select plan at the time of registration. If select premium must redirect to paypal or some payment gateway then after payment his registration complete. If select free plan then go with the normal procedure but is it possible?

Comment: if customer selected free plan set the customer group free for him there is no discount and if the customer select the premium then set premium group for him add shopping cart rule for him.

Comment: @Qaisar Satti : client wants to charge some amount at the time of registration and then he will set the product prices according to the group from the admin. Its like crowd funding the customer who invest more or pay more he will get more cheaper price for the products but customer have to pay first

Answer (score 0):

Group price already available at magento and Group price is only set for products.

So you **no need to extract code**.If you will **provide a customer to select his/her customer group**  at ***his/her registration time*** ,then whenever customer will  purchase a product then product will purchase with that product's customer select group price.

But for **buy a product with its group price then you should login at system**

Also you can not go to payment with out cart a product

Comment: client requirement is customer will register on some plan their will be free, premium plan if user register himself in free plan product price will be higher and if user select premium one products prices will be lower but how I can achive this as there is no option to add customer group price.'

Comment: Any advice on this?