# Magento 1.9: How to add customer group on registration page

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-group

I have followed every tutorial I have found and doesn't work. I am trying to add the customer groups on the customer registration page but its not working. I hope this question will help others also as all the previous questions based on this are too old. Please, check below my code:

**app/code/core/mage/customer/etc/config.xml**

```
<global>
..........
<customer_account>
 <group_id>
   <create>1</create>
   <update>1</update>
</group_id>
</customer_account>
..........
</global>
```

**app/code/core/mage/customer/controllers/AccountController.php**

```
Replace this

$customer->getGroupId();

with

if($this->getRequest()->getPost('group_id'))
{ 
   $customer->setGroupId($this->getRequest()->getPost('group_id'));
} 
else 
{
   $customer->getGroupId(); 
}
```

**app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml**

```
<div class="input-box">
<label for="group_id"><?php echo $this->__('Group') ?><span class="required">*</span></label><br/>
<select name="group_id" id="group_id" title="<?php echo $this->__('Group') ?>" class="validate-group required-entry input-text" />
<?php $groups = Mage::helper('customer')->getGroups()->toOptionArray(); ?>
<?php foreach($groups as $group){ ?>
<option value="<?php print $group['value'] ?>"><?php print $group['label'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: For all who faces same issue after done all right way but still it not work then please follow the @Qaisar Satti answer below.

Comment: As an alternative approach. Check the section Dynamic Handles second example ProxiBlue/GlobalHandle/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no problem is your code you are editing the wrong phtml file. edit this file then changes will be shown.

```
template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
```

Comment: I have edited the `template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml` but still group not show on the registration page

Comment: @muditmehrotra did you edit the correct template enable template hint http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints and make sure cache is disabled

Comment: i tested the code it is working make sure you editing on right place

Comment: Thanks alot it worked after enable the template path. Its because of the theme. Ghost theme manage its own register.phtml in persistent folder that's why changes done in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml was not working but now it show groups on registration page.

Comment: can you please check my question. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135180/magento-1-9-how-to-add-specific-customer-group-in-drop-down-list-as-product-att