# Magento 1.9: How to add specific customer group in drop down list as product attribute in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, product, admin, product-attribute, customer-group

I am working on a project in which I have created a module to create custom 
customer in manufacturer customer group now I want to add this manufacturer customer group as a product attribute to product so that when I create a product from admin there should be an drop down list from the manufacturer customer group to add the manufacturer of the product.

Comment: So what should be the value of the product attribute? A customer id?

Comment: @fschmengler : It should be the name of the customer in drop down.

Comment: @fschmengler  : I mean in drop down it should list the names but in foreign key prospects there should be the customer id in the database to associate the product with that customer. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your own **source model** for the product attribute.

### Write the source model

This is a child class of `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract`. The most important method to implement is `getAllOptions()` which returns the possible values and labels for the dropdown:

```
public function getAllOptions()
{
    if (is_null($this->_options)) {
        $customers = $this->_getManufacturerCustomers();
        $this->_options = [];
        foreach ($customers as $customer) {
            $this->_options[] = [
                'label' => $customer->getName(),
                'value' =>  $customer->getId(),
            ];
        }
    }
    return $this->_options;
}
protected function _getManufacturerCustomers()
{
    // take this value from configuration!
    $manufacturerGroup = 123;

    $customers = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');
    $customers->addAttributeToFilter('group_id', $manufacturerGroup);

    // add attributes you need to display the customer name
    $customers->addAttributeToSelect(['firstname', 'middlename' 'lastname']);

    return $customers;
}
```

I wrote `_getManufactureCustomers()` as a draft, adjust it as needed but the principle should be clear.

### Use the source model

Let's say, the product attribute is `manufacturer_customer` and the source model alias is `stack_manufacturer/attribute_source_manufacturer`. Then the install script that adds the attribute looks like this:

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'manufacturer_customer', array(
    'label'             => 'Manufacturer Customer',
    'type'              => 'int',
    'input'             => 'select',
    'source'            => 'stack_manufacturer/attribute_source_manufacturer',

    // add more parameters as required

));
```

### Flat Index

If you want the attribute to be included in the flat index (because you need it in collections in the frontend), add these methods to the source model:

```
public function getFlatColums()
{
    $columns = array(
        $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode() => array(
            'type'      => 'int',
            'unsigned'  => false,
            'is_null'   => true,
            'default'   => null,
            'extra'     => null
        )
    );
    return $columns;
}


public function getFlatUpdateSelect($store)
{
    return Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')
        ->getFlatUpdateSelect($this->getAttribute(), $store);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will try it. I am new to magento so if there is some problem in implementation will comment here :)

Comment: can you give the file paths where I can add these codes. I am new to magento so I am not getting where from where I should start. It would be a great help.

Comment: I can't give you a complete functioning module and you would not learn anything from it. So here are the things you need to know to get started: how to create a module; how to create models; how to create install scripts to add product attributes. There are plenty of good tutorials out there for these basics

Comment: I am getting this error `Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\wampserver\tandem\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php on line 816`

Comment: Here is my code to get options:

`$this->_options = array();
            $manufacturerGroup = 4;
            $customers = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');
            $customers->addAttributeToFilter('group', $manufacturerGroup);
            $customers->addAttributeToSelect(array('firstname', 'middlename', 'lastname'));
            foreach ($customers as $customer) 
            {
                $this->_options[] = array(
                    'label' => $customer->getName(),
                    'value' =>  $customer->getId(),
                );
            }`

Comment: change 'group' to 'group_id', this is the actual field name.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more thing now these manufacturers are added as a attribute to products other words products associated with manufacturers so how I can add these manufacturers to the filters on frontend. I also need to add other attributes as well in the filters on frontend. How I can do this. It would be great help.

Comment: This is a different question. But I can tell you that much, you can configure the attribute in *Catalog > Manage Attributes* to make it "available in product listing" and "filterable". Also you have to add the `getFlatColumns()` and `getFlatUpdateSelect()` methods as in my answer above.

Comment: Can you please check my another question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136439/magento-1-9-base-table-or-view-not-found-when-try-to-add-column-to-table