# Magento 1.9 : Base table or view not found when try to add column to table

Tags: magento-1.9, install-script, upgrade-script

I am trying to upgrade my module table by using the upgrade script. I am getting the error **Base table or view not found**. Please, check below the config.xml file, install script and upgrade script code:

**Config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Tandem_OenologistUser>
        <version>0.0.2</version>
    </Tandem_OenologistUser>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <oenologist>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Tandem_OenologistUser</module>
                <frontName>oenologist</frontName>
            </args>
        </oenologist>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <oenologist>
                <file>oenologist.xml</file>
            </oenologist>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <tandem_oenologistuser_adminhtml>
           <class>Tandem_OenologistUser_Block_Adminhtml</class>
        </tandem_oenologistuser_adminhtml>
    </blocks>

    <helpers>
        <tandem_oenologistuser>
            <class>Tandem_OenologistUser_Helper</class>
        </tandem_oenologistuser>
    </helpers>

    <models>
        <tandem_oenologistuser>
            <class>Tandem_OenologistUser_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>tandem_oenologistuser_resource</resourceModel>
        </tandem_oenologistuser>
        <tandem_oenologistuser_resource>
            <class>Tandem_OenologistUser_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <oenologist>
                    <table>tandem_oenologistuser_oenologist</table>
                </oenologist>
            </entities>
        </tandem_oenologistuser_resource>
    </models>

    <resources>
        <tandem_oenologistuser_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Tandem_OenologistUser</module>
                <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </tandem_oenologistuser_setup>
    </resources>

</global>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <tandem_oenologistuser_admin>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
               <module>Tandem_OenologistUser_Adminhtml</module>
                <frontName>oenologist-user-admin</frontName>
            </args>
        </tandem_oenologistuser_admin>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

**install-0.0.1.php**

```
<?php
$this->startSetup();

$table = new Varien_Db_Ddl_Table();

$table->setName($this->getTable('tandem_oenologistuser_oenologist'));

$table->addColumn(
'entity_id',
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
10,
array(
    'auto_increment' => true,
    'unsigned' => true,
    'nullable'=> false,
    'primary' => true
)
);
$table->addColumn(
'created_at',
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
null,
array(
    'nullable' => false,
)
);
$table->addColumn(
'updated_at',
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
null,
array(
    'nullable' => false,
)
);
$table->addColumn(
'name',
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR,
255,
array(
    'nullable' => false,
)
);
$table->addColumn(
'email',
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR,
255,
array(
    'nullable' => false,
)
);
$table->addColumn(
'url_key',
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR,
255,
array(
    'nullable' => false,
)
);
$table->addColumn(
'description',
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
null,
array(
    'nullable' => false,
)
);
$table->addColumn(
'visibility',
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_BOOLEAN,
null,
array(
    'nullable' => false,
)
);
$table->addColumn(
'customer_id',
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR,
255,
array(
    'nullable' => false,
)
);
$table->addColumn(
'instagramid',
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR,
500,
array(
    'nullable' => false,
)
);
$table->addColumn(
'facebookid',
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR,
500,
array(
    'nullable' => false,
)
);
$table->addColumn(
'twitterid',
Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR,
500,
array(
    'nullable' => false,
)
);

$table->setOption('type', 'InnoDB');
$table->setOption('charset', 'utf8');

$this->getConnection()->createTable($table);

$this->endSetup();
```

**upgrade-0.0.1-0.0.2.php***

```
$installer = $this;
$connection = $installer->getConnection();

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('tandem_oenologistuser/oenologist'),
    'customer_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, 255,
    array(
        'nullable' => true,
        'default' => null,
        'comment' => 'customer id'
    )
)
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('tandem_oenologistuser/oenologist'),
    'instagramtoken', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, 500,
    array(
        'nullable' => true,
        'default' => null,
        'comment' => 'instagram oauth token'
    )
)
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('tandem_oenologistuser/oenologist'),
    'facebooktoken', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, 500,
    array(
        'nullable' => true,
        'default' => null,
        'comment' => 'facebook oauth token'
    )
)
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('tandem_oenologistuser/oenologist'),
    'twittertoken', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, 500,
    array(
        'nullable' => true,
        'default' => null,
        'comment' => 'twitter oauth token'
    )
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

Table is present in database. Can I add columns manually?

Comment: you have to keep filename mysql4-upgrade-0.0.1-0.0.2.php

Comment: nothing happened same error still

Comment: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 La table '255.tandem_oenologistuser_oenologist' n'existe pas in C:\wamp\www\wampserver\tandem\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 228

Comment: old table already exists ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep below code in your **mysql4-upgrade-0.0.1-0.0.2.php** file,

```
<?php

$this->startSetup();

$this->run("
    ALTER TABLE `{$this->getTable('tandem_oenologistuser_oenologist')}` ADD `customer_id`  VARCHAR(255);
    ALTER TABLE `{$this->getTable('tandem_oenologistuser_oenologist')}` ADD `instagramtoken` TEXT;
    ALTER TABLE `{$this->getTable('tandem_oenologistuser_oenologist')}` ADD `facebooktoken`  TEXT;
    ALTER TABLE `{$this->getTable('tandem_oenologistuser_oenologist')}` ADD `twittertoken`  TEXT;
"); 

$this->endSetup();
```

Comment: It will also worked if I use this module with some other magento installation. I mean it will create complete table?

Comment: yes this is work for other magento as well.

Comment: How I can select data from a table according to any column. Please help. like if I need to select data according to customer Id from my custom table. Table structure is `(id, name, customer_id, instagram_token)`

Comment: I have tried this:

`$oenologist = Mage::getModel('tandem_oenologistuser/oenologist');
                        $oenologist->load($customer_id);
                        $oenologist->setInstagramtoken($token);
                        $oenologist->save();`

But not working. I am new to magento

Comment: The solution you given above not working when I again want to modify my table. Do you have any idea why its not working. This time my version is `0.0.3` sql upgrade script name `mysql4-upgrade-0.0.2-0.0.3.php` version number updated in config.xml but still new columns not added and no error show

Comment: remove cache folder and clear cache and reindex it and check

Comment: not working I have clear cache, reindex data still same no column added :(

Comment: any idea why its not working?

Comment: Should I delete table and run again. Any suggestion?

Comment: This is the proper way you did it, but not tell from here, what is the problem for you.. you can try with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to stick with the table name I used in the installation script, especially if I had table prefixes.

You used `getTable('tandem_oenologistuser_oenologist')` in the installation script, 
but you use `getTable('tandem_oenologistuser/oenologist')` in the upgrade script.

Comment: I have also tried this `getTable('tandem_oenologistuser/oenologist')` in upgrade script also but it's not working @Rahesh answer worked for me. Thanks for the comment

Comment: I'm saying the the exact opposite. Try getTable('tandem_oenologistuser_oenologist') instead