# Magento 1.9 : How to override/overwrite customer module core files

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, theme, customer-account

I need to **add some custom controller actions in customer module core files** in magento. How I can do this without touching the core files? I need to update the following files from the core customer module:

`frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml`

`app/code/core/mage/customer/controller/AccountController.php, navigation`

`frontend/base/default/template/customer/account/navigation.phtml`

`frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml`

Another file is the theme file which I also need to override/overwrite:

`frontend/mtghost/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *a) frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml*

You should not override this file. If you want to make any in layout, create a new ***local.xml*** file in your theme.

> b) app/code/core/mage/customer/controller/AccountController.php

You must create a module for overriding the ***AccountController.php*** file as follow.

**1) app/etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**2) app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <namespace_module before="Mage_Customer">Namespace_Module</namespace_module>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**3) app/code/local/Namespace/Module/controllers/AccountController.php**

```
<?php
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Customer').DS.'AccountController.php');

class Namespace_Module_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{
    /**
     * Override the required function here, 
     * e.g. createAction
     */
    public function createAction()
    {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/login');
    }
}
```

That's the proper way you should use to override the controller.

> c) frontend/base/default/template/customer/account/navigation.phtml

Simple place this file in your theme using the same hierarchy as follow.

```
frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/customer/account/navigation.phtml
```

> d)
>   frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml

Simple place this file in your theme using the same hierarchy as follow.

```
frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
```

> *e) frontend/mtghost/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml*

This file is already in a custom theme. If its your theme then there is no harm in editing in it. If you have another theme then place this file in it as follow and override.

```
frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

f) For adding custom tab in customer account, add the file with content below.

> frontend/your_package/your_theme/layout/local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink">
                <name>custom_tab</name>
                <path>customtab/index/index</path>
                <label>My custom tab</label>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer. Can I add new functions also in the AccountController.php file and these functions will add to the customer module right?

Comment: Yes you can add new as well as override old ones. Also you can call the parent class functions which is the true essence of overriding.

Comment: Thanks and I am using the mtghost magento theme so should I add all the xml in mtghost/default/layout/local.xml which I need to add in frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml

Comment: I need to add a new link in account section sidebar of the customer of specific group that's why I have edited the core customer.xml. I have add all the xml in local.xml of the theme but its not working

Comment: I am not using my own theme I am using mtghost magento theme so I have edited its file directly is there any issue with it. Please, suggest as I am new to magento

Comment: yes you can add your xml snippet in that local.xml

Comment: It should work in local.xml. Make sure you're using the same hierarchy for xml nodes. Thanks for accepting my answer :)

Comment: @ Muhammad Saiid : added but not working. I have added same in customer.xml and it add a link in customer account

Answer (score 1):

You should have your own theme for overwriting template files.
something like:

> frontend/yourtheme/default/layout/customer.xml

put files you want to overwrite in the exact same part in your theme.
configure that the shop uses your theme in magento backend:

system/configuration/general/design/ adjust here **package** & **theme**

*but there are different ways to do so + you should inform you a bit more*

## your core file problem

i think simplest solution is:

duplicate that file

> app/code/core/mage/customer/controller/AccountController.php

into

> app/code/**local**/mage/customer/controller/AccountController.php

make your changes.

*but generally you should have an own module and extend your desired function.*

Comment: So I need to add the `require_once 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';` in my custom controller file right?

Comment: also how to inform magento that my module has override function for the customer account? Is it the config.xml that do this but how?

Comment: You cannot override controller by just changing the code pool b'coz its not bind with autoload class of magento